# Reasons for attributes' performance increase in Kdb+?

Tags: kdb

I have some questions about the attributes in q/kdb/kdb+. I would like to know when and why one would use the grouped attribute as opposed to the parted attribute and why these 2 attributes cause performance improvements.

1)My understanding is that using the parted attribute on the sym column for tables on disk allows for faster queries that filter for sym by storing the sorted sym column as a hash table with each symbol as a key and the first index of each sym as a value. Is the improved performance due to the query not having to load in as much data into memory compared to if no attribute was applied?

2)The timestored website says that the parted attribute is used because “with hard disk drives, seek time to find a data location is significant but once the location is found the data transfer rate is high”  Is this essentially saying that the time taken for the diskhead to move to a further away memory address is longer than if it is able to just read memory addresses next to each other in contiguous memory (which the parted attribute allows for) Is this correct?

3)Following from the above question, what about with SSD’s which don’t have a moving diskhead, will they still have improved query speeds when the parted attribute is applied on disk and if so why?
I’d also like to know why is the grouped attribute used for tables in memory and the parted attribute used for tables on disk? Couldn’t the grouped attribute be used for tables on disk so that you are just doing a O(1) lookup in a hash table and then you have all the indices for that symbol available.

4)q for mortals says that the parted attribute is more effective that the grouped attribute for in memory tables too. Does anyone know why this might be?

applying atributes on disk and in memory

Answer (score 3):

I'll answer your questions as best I can.

1. Yes, the improved performance comes as a result of kdb knowing in advance exactly which indices it needs to read from disk, rather than reading the entire column and filtering.
2. Yes, similar to answer 1 above.
3. I haven't seen or done much testing on SSD drives, perhaps someone else can comment on this, there may be information relevant on the Intel Optane stuff (https://code.kx.com/q/kb/optane). Re the second part, the grouped attribute could be used on disk indeed - however the lookup table created consumes the most memory of any attribute. This lookup table would also have to be stored on disk, consuming more resources. (I don't know how the read from disk operates under the grouped attribute)

```
    q)l:1000000?10?`3
    q)`:p/ set .Q.en[`:.;]@[;`sym;`p#]([]sym:asc l)
    `:p/
    q)`:g/ set .Q.en[`:.;]@[;`sym;`g#]([]sym:asc l)
    `:g/
```

On disk, you can see the increased size of the grouped attribute file.

```
$ ls -ltrh [pg]
p:
total 3924
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user group 3.9M Nov 22 11:07 sym
g:
total 7852
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user group 7.7M Nov 22 11:07 sym
```

And in memory (in a new q session), the query on parted is faster:

```
q)sym:get`:sym;system each"l ",/:"pg"
`p`g
q)\ts do[1000;select from p where sym in`iok]
112 1049200j
q)\ts do[1000;select from g where sym in`iok]
122 1049200j
```

4. I'd imagine it's faster for the same reason as 1 and 2, kdb+ only needs to read a certain subset of indices from the table. In practice, grouped is used as the parted attribute is not suitable for a real time table. Even if you could somehow ensure that the symbols arrived in the correct order, the parted attribute is never preserved on any operation, so you would need to re-apply it on each new entry to the table. Grouped, on the other hand, does preserve the attribute on append, so new entries can be added to the table, without having to re-apply it.

Comment: Size of grouped attribute is comparable to the size of the original data, and kdb has to read the whole thing into memory. Meaning you lose twice: firstly you lose any benefit of memory mapping for just the data you need, and then you *still* have to read the indices you want to find the actual data.